# one of gpu or cpu，the result is right，when test both，the result is mistake

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

this is my code

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

torch.manual_seed(200)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(200)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(200)

input_v = torch.randn(160, 12, 320, 320)

def result_cuda():
    input = input_v.cuda()
    print("gpu shape = ", input.shape, " mean = ", input.mean().cpu().detach())
    model = nn.Conv2d(12, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    model = model.cuda()
    out = model(input)
    print("gpu shape = ", out.shape, " mean = ", out.mean().cpu().detach())

def result_cpu():
    input = input_v
    print("cpu shape = ", input.shape, " mean = ", input.mean().detach())
    model = nn.Conv2d(12, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    out = model(input)
    print("cpu shape = ", out.shape, " mean = ", out.mean().detach())

result_cuda()
result_cpu()
```

when i run result_cuda(), the result is as follows

> gpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 12, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(2.1668e-05)
>
> gpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 32, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(7.5935e-06)

when i run result_cpu(), the result is as follows

> cpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 12, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(2.1668e-05)
>
> cpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 32, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(7.5936e-06)

but when i run both result_cpu() and result_cuda(), the result is as follows

> gpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 12, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(2.1668e-05)
>
> gpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 32, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(7.5935e-06)
>
> cpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 12, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(2.1668e-05)
>
> cpu shape =  torch.Size([160, 32, 320, 320])  mean =
> tensor(-1.1677e-05)

why does this happen ？

Comment: You set the random seed before `result_cuda` when alone, before `result_cpu` when alone, and before `result_cuda` when doing both; but not before `result_cpu` when doing both. Thus, `result_cpu` in your last experiment is getting a different random number sequence than the solo `result_cpu`, leading to different results.

Comment: I have modified the code as follow,  add  `torch.manual_seed(200)` before `result_cpu()`, but the result is still not equal